# DirectXTk GeometricPrimitive texture coordinates

Tags: directx, directx-11

I'm using GeometricPrimitive for some scene elements, but it's Draw() call always uses TX coords of 0-1 with no opportunity (I think) to change it.

If I just change the texcoords in the DirectXTk code itself, I can get textures to repeat by using larger texture coordinates; clearly though I don't want to be dependent on hacking the toolkit code.

So, since the Draw() provides a lambda callback, I'm wondering if there's any opportunity to remedy this by updating the texture coordinates.

I'm also using BasicEffect to do the rendering.

They use VertexPositionNormalTexture which is publicly accessible.  If that somehow provides me a way to walk their vertex buffer and update the TX coords, that would work for me.  I'm wondering if I can Map() or somehow else access their buffer, walk the vertices, update the TX coords, and hope for the best.

Is this the best (only) approach or is there a better one for GeometricPrimitive?

Comment: What kind of mapping in particular are you trying to achieve and what shape? The same mapping with repeats? Something else?

Comment: Just repeating a brick pattern on a plane (thin box, actually), nothing fancy.  If I hack the tx coords to 100 instead of 1, they repeat with WRAP as the rasterizer state.  Works great, but I don't want to hack their code or I become dependent on a modified DirectXTK

Comment: Opened an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/issues/14) on GitHub to expose this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up writing my own shader to render the primitives and added a UV transform.  This allowed me to pass in XMMatrixScaling(10,10,10) for example to scale the coords and get a larger repeat.

Comment: That works. I've made some changes to ``GeometricPrimitive`` for the next release so you can get a ``std::vector`` of the verts and faces it generates, modify them, and then create a ``GeometricPrimitive`` from the new data. They are in the master branch on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) if you want to try them out.

Comment: For example code how on to use the new functionality, see the DirectX Tool Kit [docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/GeometricPrimitive#custom-geometry)